# For a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ where $p$ is a prime number, show that $O(N(a))=p^2$.

Tags: group-theory

> For a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ where $p$ is a prime number, show that $O(N(a))=p^2$.

The class equation: $O(G)=|Z(G)|+\sum_{a\in T, a \not\in Z(G)}\left\lvert \frac{O(G)}{O(N(a))}\right\rvert$, where, $T $ is set of representative of each class.

Now, I know that for any group of order $p^{\alpha}$ the center of the the group, $Z(G)$ is non-trivial. Now, using class equation, and the fact that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic implies G is abelian, it can be shown that in this case $|Z(G)|=p$.

Now, my book directly states that: For all $a \not\in Z(G)$, $O(N(a))=p^2.$ I am unable to verify this fact. How did the direct calculation of $O(N(a))$ happen here.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that always $Z(G) \subseteq N(a)$. If $a \notin Z(G)$, then $Z(G)$ is a *proper* subgroup of $N(a)$. Hence $|N(a):Z(G)|$ is at least $p$. If it would be $p^2$, then $G=N(a)$, which is equivalent to $a \in Z(G)$. Hence $|N(a)|=p^2$.

Comment: Thanks for making it this simple. +1

Comment: No problem, you are welcome!!!